# Save spreadsheet to folder with sheets api v4

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Here's the link to the api: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/

I'm trying to figure out how to save this spreadsheet to a folder in google drive. The only thing I've found is this:   (https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.sheets/copyTo)

The problem is, I get errors when I do `"destinationSpreadsheetId": folder id` inside the `properties`. So I'm not sure if that is the right way to do it or if there even is a way to create a new spreadsheet into a folder using sheets api v4.

```
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.create({
    "sheets": [
      {
        "properties": {
          "gridProperties": {
            "rowCount": 1,
            "columnCount": 3
          }
        },
        "data": [
          {
            "rowData": [
              {
                "values": [
                  {
                    "userEnteredValue": {"stringValue": "one"}
                  },
                  {
                    "userEnteredValue": {"stringValue": "two"}
                  },
                  {
                    "userEnteredValue": {"stringValue": "three"}
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "properties": {
      "title": name
    }
  });
```

---

Also, how would I get a spreadsheets id by a name being passed into a function?

```
function getSpreadsheetId(name)
{
  //get file 'name' id from folder
}
```

Comment: Will this be helpful for you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42966153/creating-spreadsheets-using-advanced-drive-services/42967100#42967100

Comment: @Tanaike sort of, but is there a way to add creating it into a folder inside like the properties of the Sheets.Spreadsheets.create?

Comment: When I solved to the question, also I have been looking for the method, however I have never been able to find it. So I proposed the change of parents using ``Drive.Files.update``. Although ``Sheets.Spreadsheets.create`` can give the name, it cannot give the parents.

Comment: Assigning parent folders to files is the task of Drive API

Comment: @Tanaike is there a way to get the file id using spreadsheet.create? If there is, how would I set it to a var, like var fileId?

Comment: You can retrieve ID using ``Sheets.Spreadsheets.create(p).spreadsheetId``.

Comment: @Tanaike I meant like from within the create json. Like sheets > properties > set id to a var? Like for the drive.files part, how would i get the id so i can move it into a folder?

Comment: In order to retrieve spreadsheet ID using ``sheets.spreadsheets.create``, ``fields=spreadsheetId`` has to be used as a query string. This cannot be used in request body (json). So to use this on GAS, ``Sheets.Spreadsheets.create(p).spreadsheetId`` has to be used. You can see the detail information. https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets I'm sorry that I could not fulfill your require.